# React-Native Promise.all and Multiple API Requests

Tags: api, react-native, promise

I'm trying to pull 2 different API requests from OpenWeather for a weather app written in React-Native.  I'm new to using API's anyway, but I'm also trying to use 2 at the same time.  I've gone through a dozen turorials and cannot get it to work.  The most resent one looked pretty straight forward, but I keep getting linting errors.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the most recent code / try.  My linter keeps saying that the ; or , after...

`let currentWeather => finalVals[0];`

`let dailyWeather => finalVals[1];`

...are wrong, but changing them doesnt help anything either.  Here is the link to this turotial I was using too: https://medium.com/@gianpaul.r/fetching-from-multiple-api-endpoints-at-once-ffb1b54600f9

And here is my code:

```
_getWeather = (lat, long) => {

     let currentWeather = fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&APPID=${API_KEY}`);
     let dailyWeather = fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&APPID=${API_KEY}`);

     Promise.all([currentWeather, dailyWeather])
      .then(values => Promise.all(values.map(value => value.json())))
      .then(finalVals => {
        let currentWeather => finalVals[0];
        let dailyWeather => finalVals[1];

        this.setState({
          temperature: Math.floor((currentWeather.main.temp) - 273.15),
          name: currentWeather.weather[0].main,
          location: currentWeather.name,
          isLoaded: true
        });
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sigh...after banging my head on the wall for an hour, I realized I had function arrows where there shouldn't have been.  Deepest apologies for the post, unless anyone sees any other problems with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Eric, glad you found your error!
Alternatively you can greatly simplify your function for readability and clarity using the await syntax.

```
  _getWeather = async(lat, long) => {

 let currentWeatherEndpoint = fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&APPID=${API_KEY}`);
 let dailyWeatherEndpoint = fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&APPID=${API_KEY}`);

 let finalVals = await Promise.all([currentWeatherEndpoint, dailyWeatherEndpoint])

    let currentWeather = finalVals[0];
    let dailyWeather = finalVals[1];

    this.setState({
      temperature: Math.floor((currentWeather.main.temp) - 273.15),
      name: currentWeather.weather[0].main,
      location: currentWeather.name,
      isLoaded: true
  });

};
```

Comment: Thank you for that @cleme001.  Even though I found the error, you gave me a little something extra and I really appreciate that.